Can i have two versions of one App with different BundleIds
Our company has two online iOS Apps, one is the old App and the other is the refactored App. Now the company wants to replace the old App with the refactored App while retaining the refactored App. This way, it can pass Is it audited by Apple? Are there any risks?
It has not been implemented yet and is in the research stage.

IMO, I think it's fine unless it comes from a different account, if this is the case, you may encounter 4.3 (spam) problem. How about replacing the new one with the same bundle ID? Do you need to keep both apps?

Yes, Keep two apps. I already know about this 4.3 (spam) problem，
Is there any way to solve it?

As I already stated, if two apps come from the same developer program account, I suppose it's fine. My company has already done that, previously, we had 2 apps with 90% of the same functionality. However, as far as I am aware, there is no documentation regarding this potential concern.
